# How to make different actions after click button in blocks the same name classes (Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two blocks with the same html. And when I try to add effect after click button in js, it works in both blocks. How can I fix it? Thank you for help.

```
<div class="class-1">
     <div class="red-line"></div>

     <div class="first-btn"></div>
     <div class="second-btn" style="display:none;"></div>

     <div class="my-content">545646</div>
</div>

<div class="class-1">
     <div class="red-line"></div>

     <div class="first-btn"></div>
     <div class="second-btn" style="display:none;"></div>

     <div class="my-content">12323</div>
</div>
```

My js:

```
$('.first-btn').click(function() {
  $('.red-line').css('display' , 'none');
  $('.my-content').css('height' , '500px');

  $('.second-btn').css('display' , 'block');
  $('.first-btn').css('display' , 'none');
});
```

Comment: Use the parent() jquery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the parent and then select the child in it like following.

```
$('.first-btn').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    $('.red-line', parent).css('display', 'none');
    $('.my-content', parent).css('height', '500px');

    $('.second-btn', parent).css('display', 'block');
    $('.first-btn', parent).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify element in the current element context i.e. `this`. Use `.closest()` to traverse up to parent then use `.find()` / `.children()` to find the  desired elements.

```
$('.first-btn').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.class-1');
    parent.find('.red-line').css('display' , 'none');
    parent.find('.my-content').css('height' , '500px');

    parent.find('.second-btn').css('display' , 'block');
    $(this).css('display' , 'none');
});
```

As an alternative you can also use `siblings()`

```
$('.first-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.red-line').css('display' , 'none');
    $(this).siblings('.my-content').css('height' , '500px');

    $(this).siblings('.second-btn').css('display' , 'block');
    $(this).css('display' , 'none');
});
```

Comment: many thanks, it works. my big problem for understanding 'this' selector (